# Хостинг JAVA/JSF 2.+ проектов

Tags: jsf, java

Кто подскажет качественные хостинги для `JAVA/JSF 2.+` проектов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jelastic.com](http://jelastic.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[firstvds.ru](http://firstvds.ru/?from=103559)

Если зарегаешся по ссылке, то получишь скидку.
Это выделенный сервер по 149 рублей в месяц, очень дешего